# what is this program  (Reversing a String) in C not working?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n=0;
char str[]="karthik";
while(*(str+n)!='0')
n++;
for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
{char temp=str[i];
str[i]=str[n-i-1];str[n-i-1]=temp;
}
printf("%s",str);
}
```

I know this is Pretty common question but when i tried i am not getting any output.I know that there is some error in below two lines because when i used strlen() it worked well.

```
while(*(str+n)!='0')
n++;
```

so please say why is it wrong to use like this. please remember i am a beginner in c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while(*(str+n)!='0') 
n++;
```

The idea is to iterate through the array for the entire length of the string.
You should be checking for `\0`. Because c strings are null terminated(`\0`)

```
while(*(str+n)!='\0')
                 ^^
```

---

Also, on a side note You should return a value from your `main()` function, irrelevant to the problem but it is a good practice.

Comment: @karthikgorijavolu: No Problem. Added a small side note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

End of a char array in c == `'\0'`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the null termination issue, you must adopt a conventional coding style. One example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  int n=0;
  char str[]="karthik";

  while(str[n] != '\0')
  {
    n++;
  }

  for(i=0; i<n/2; i++)
  {
    char temp=str[i];
    str[i]=str[n-i-1];
    str[n-i-1]=temp;
  }

  printf("%s",str);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for NULL in while loop.
Change from

```
while(*(str+n)!='0')
```

To

```
while(*(str+n)!='\0')
```

Comment: NULL is not the same as '\0'! NULL might often be defined as (void*)0 and then you might get compiler warnings from this code. NULL should only be used to compare pointer addresses with.